# Presented View Controller Has Wrong Frame When Orientation Changes

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom UINavigationController (only customized to standardize colors and a few other things) that I use throughout my iPhone app. When I rotate my phone, everything works fine. Unfortunately, when I use said controller with presentViewController, things get weird after rotating.

[image: wonky image]

Do I have to do anything special with a view controller that is presented to make it play well with orientation changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar happened with my app.

I was presenting the view controller from a ChildViewController. I changed the presenting view controller to the parentViewController instead of the childViewController, and it worked properly.

I hope this help you!

Regards,
Martin.